# Route chaining in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing

Laravel has this pretty syntax:

```
Route::{$method}('/user/{id}', "Controller@method")->name("user")
```

But whats the magic behind it?

Route is a Facade for `Illuminate\Routing\Router` which itself has the methods for `GET POST PUT DELTE` and so on. But every method returns `$this->addRoute()` which in itself returns `\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection::add()` and this finally returns a variable called `$route`, which contains the `Route`. There are some steps in between (creation of the Route instance is already done in `Router` by a method which also then adds the route to the route collection).

But finally, an object of class `Illuminate\Routing\Route` is returned.
How does this deal with things like chaining the `name()`? Does it write the name into a separate object which resides in the `$collection` of `Router`?

Thanks in advance for your most helpful answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interestingly this hasn't always been possible. In Laravel 4 you couldn't name a route from the `Route` object itself (though you could do other stuff that was more directly relevant to the route) but in 5 you now can.

So a quick primer on chaining: by returning `$this` in a method, you allow this kind of method chaining `$route->name('whatever')->where('id', '\d+')`. That, I presume, you already know.

So the additional layer of facade is nothing special - the facade's `get`/`post`/etc. method just returns the `Route` instance (eventually, as you say!) which is then ripe for chaining.

So here's where it gets fun. In Laravel 4, the naming of a `Route` was only available on `RouteCollection`, not on the `Route` itself - that's because the `RouteCollection` managed the `Route`s' names. Nowadays, that is no longer the case. Each `Route` stores its own name.

If you check out the `RouteCollection` class, you'll see there's a method [refreshNameLoopups](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/de142d2e73bd2911dc3f039ab291247338962001/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php#L108) [[2](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.html#method_refreshNameLookups)] which is used as part of the route matching mechanism to get each route's name and cache is locally for a quick lookup.

So that's how the `Route` can 'tell' its parent `RouteCollection` what it should call it :)

Comment: @Kyslik thanks for the edit - I always forget about the API docs :)

Comment: No problem artisan; I always look in API first, was crafting answer when yours got pushed :)